# How can I retrieve an image which is saved in the photolibrary of an android system?

Tags: cordova, base64, photolibrary

I'm trying to acces the photolibrary of an android system to retrieve an image. I have the imageURI variable provided by the navigator.camera.getPicture function. That's ok until then. But later, I want to access the photolibrary and take the base64 code of this image.

Since is not possible that navigator.camera.getPicture returns both data (imageURI and imageData), I need to get the base64 information later. Here is the code I tried to use, looking at "file" documentation of phoneGap, but it doesn't work.

It stops at "fileSystem.root.getFile" call - (Error in error callback: File4 = TypeError: Result of expression 'evt.target' [undefined] is not an object. at file:///android_asset/www/phonegap-1.3.0.js:717)

Who could help me? Thanks.

```
    function base64(imageURI) {
 alert(imageURI);
 document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady);

 function onDeviceReady() {
     window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);}

 function gotFS(fileSystem) {
     alert("filesystem");
             //Next line causes error. Perhaps imageURI is not a valid path?
     fileSystem.root.getFile(**imageURI**, null, gotFileEntry, fail);}


 function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
     alert("gotfileentry");
     fileEntry.file(gotFile, fail);}

 function gotFile(file){
     alert("got file");
     readDataUrl(file);}

 function readDataUrl(file) {
     alert("readDataURL");
     var reader = new FileReader();
     reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
         console.log("Read as data URL");
         alert(evt.target.result);
         };
     reader.readAsDataURL(file);
 }
 function fail(evt) {
     console.log(evt.target.error.code);}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, the first problem is that the object returned by your fail function doesn't have the property you're trying to access. To see what's in the error object, try this:

```
 function fail(evt) {
                 alert("there was an error: " + JSON.stringify(evt));
            }
```

Let us know what that produces...

Comment: His code comes directly from PhoneGap's API. But JSON.stringify only returns { "code" : X}. So you should log evt.code.

Comment: ?? My point was that he shouldn't log/alert evt.target.error.code but just evt.code..

Comment: I prefer to stringify the entire object because there could be other relevant information within it..

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you need the getPicture to return both URI and Data.

If you need to display the picture you can ask the getPicture to return the data in base 64 :

```
    function capturePhoto(){
        navigator.camera.getPicture(
            addPictureToActuSuccess, 
            addPictureToActuFail, {
                quality: 50,
                destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
                sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
            }
        );
    }

    function addPictureToActuSuccess(data){
        // Store the base64 data in a file or in a variable
    }

    function addPictureToActuFail(error){
        console.log(error);
    }
```

and display it with css :

```
url('data:image/png;base64,BASE64_DATA') /* From where you stored you base64 data */
```

That way, you can also store the base 64 data and display the picture

Comment: This doesn't work in iphone and blackberry..it only returns file uri not base 64 encoded string ...

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that the imageURI returned from the API must be stripped of the file protocol:

```
var rf=app.profile.customer.site.imageURI.substring(16); // strip off file://localhost
var reader=new FileReader();
reader.onloadend=function(evt){
  // the image data is in :  evt.target.result
  // it starts with:  data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/....
  // so you may need to strip off the first 24 chars
}
reader.readAsDataURL(rf);
```

Also, as above, you don't need to do the FileSystem/FileEntry/File thing; you can just create a FileReader since you have the fully qualified URI.

This worked for me on iOS.  I'll be testing Android soon and will post back my results.